# Difference between these two probabilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**EDIT: I just noticed that they are the same thing. Sorry!**

What is the difference between these two probability questions? I don't understand why one would solve them differently.

```
1) Draw 5 cards from a deck of 52, what is the probability that all 5 are spades?
```

and

```
2) What is the probability that 5 spades are drawn in a row?
```

My course notes solves the first one by $\frac{13\choose 5}{52\choose5}$ which makes perfect sense to me. And they solve the second by $\frac{13\times12\times11\times10\times9}{52\times51\times50\times49\times48}$ which also kinda makes sense.

Can someone shed some light as to how these are different?

Comment: The two questions (and the two answers) coincide.

Comment: Haha, you're right. I guess I typed it into my calculator wrong the first time.

Comment: It's worth looking at both methods. Straight counting (as in the first approach) and term by term (probability of the first spade is $\frac {13}{52}$ and so on.  Both methods come up a lot, sometimes (though not here) one is easier to use than the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As lulu noted in a comment, both the questions and the answers coincide.